# IIF THEN in MDX for handling ∞ values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

I am getting an

### ∞

value in my calculated measures.
I want to handle this value, & if it comes, it should display 0.

What I tried is,

```
 1. IIF([Meaures].[Plant Share] = "∞" , 0, [Meaures].[Plant Share])

 2. IIF([Meaures].[Plant Share] = "Infinity" , 0, [Meaures].[Plant Share])
```

Both seems not working.

In query output, I am getting **∞** as *`Infinity`*.

Any Idea how should I ?

Thanks.

Bytheway, to type **∞**,

```
Windows  ALT + 2 3 6
Macintosh Inser --> Symbol -> ∞
```

**UPDATE:**
This way I calculate the member.

```
WITH
MEMBER [Meaures].[Plant Share] AS(
([Meaures].[YTD Plant Share] / [Meaures].[PY YTD Plant Share] - 1 ) * 100
)
```

Comment: Is your measure coming straight from the cube or is it a calculated measure? If it's a calculated measure it's best to acomodate the case when the denominator is zero in the definition of the calculated member.

Comment: Further to the comment above, could you share the definition of the [Plant Share] measure? Either the MDX if it's a calculated measure or the SQL if it's from the DSV or a DB view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your measure to the following:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Meaures].[Plant Share] AS(
    iif
    ([Meaures].[PY YTD Plant Share] = 0,
    null,
    ([Meaures].[YTD Plant Share] / [Meaures].[PY YTD Plant Share] - 1 ) * 100
    )
)
```

Comment: yes thats the only way in MDX. I am using SSRS so I have done this at report level using expression. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome trick I found for this situation.

Simply use Divide function, newly introduced.

```
Divide (<numerator>, <denominator> [,<alternateresult>])
```

For more details, refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj873944.aspx).